# Chat com notificação de aviso em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Estou desenvolvendo um chat com o *Laravel*, e [segui este tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel). O chat está funcionando certinho, porém queria saber como fazer para aparecer uma notificação desse tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando uma mensagem é enviada para um usuário e o mesmo ainda não leu.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você deve usar o Laravel Notifications junto com o Pusher ou Laravel Echo

Comment: Boa tarde. Usar esse cara aqui https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications     ?

Comment: Exato,  os tutoriais do Jeffrey Way usa ele.

Comment: Certo. Vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado

Comment: Vídeo certo: https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1

Comment: Você quer em tempo real?

Comment: Sim sim... Estilo Facebook sabe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua migration "messages", adicione:

```
 $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
```

Com esse campo, você poderá saber as mensagens que já foram lidas e as que não foram.

Agora, basta você fazer uma busca por mensagens não lidas dessa forma:

```
$mensagemsNaoLidas = App\Message::where('user_id', $user_id)->whereNull('read_at')->get();
```

E retornar a sua view os valores, assim:

```
return view('suaview', $mensagensNaoLidas);
```

Com isso, você passa para a sua view essas mensagens não lidas e formata de acordo com a foto dessa forma:

```
a.notif {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url(...url para o icone...);
  background-size: contain;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.num {
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}

<a href="" class="notif">
<span class="num">
<?php
     echo count($mensagensNaoLidas);
?>
</span></a>
```

Dessa forma, exibirá conforme a imagem, e depois, você decide como quer que o código decida quando ele leu uma mensagem.

Comment: Boa tarde Vinicius. Mas nesse caso que você me passou, eu usaria alguma evento para ficar verificando se tem novas mensagens? Tipo algum evento Ajax?

Comment: Pela pergunta, eu entendi que não precisava ser em tempo real, então eu fiz ele estático, apenas atualiza as notificações ao recarregar a página. Você pode usar o Ajax para verificar de tempos em tempos se há novas mensagens. Há também a possibilidade de reutilizar o código que você usou para atualizar a página em tempo real ao receber mensagens para atualizar as notificações.

Comment: Boa noite Vinicius. Do jeito que você me falou funcionou. Obrigado.